# pdf file renamed in email

Tags: pdf, phpmailer, fpdf

I am struggling with the file name of a PDF created on the fly (FPDF 1.82) using PHPMAILER (6.3.0) under PHP 5.6.17

```
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('pdf_doc.pdf', 'S');
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfdoc, 'pdf_doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
```

**Everything works fine** only the attached PDF file is renamed `.$path` !
The file sent is a perfectly readable non corrupted pdf file.

`$doc = $pdf->Output('pdf_doc.pdf', 'F');` downloads the file with the proper name !!!

The only clue would be in the error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' with
> message 'Could not access file: ' in ....
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addAttachment('', 'pdf_doc.pdf')

meaning that the `$doc` is not recognised

Well, you know everything ...Any idea of what can go wrong with this pdf title ?

Many thanks

Comment: Not specifically an issue here, but upgrade your PHP. 5.6 is no longer supported, and later versions are safer, faster, and more capable. Nobody should be doing new development using ancient PHP versions.

Comment: Can you show the MIME header for the attachment showing the exact output that is produced in a delivered message, or in debug output?

Comment: Content-Type: application/pdf; name=.$path
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.$path

Comment: It looks like a quoting problem, but I can't reproduce this. Can you post your complete code?

Comment: I have started migrating to PHP7; I'll get back to you as soon as I am done debugging
Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: Working fine now that I migrated to PHP 7 as well as I downloaded the latest PHPmailer.php file